# how to get any gps coordinates without listeners or requestLocationUpdates

Tags: android, gps

I only need the last known gps location from any provider
without telling any provider to update.

Is this possible without adding listeners or requestLocationUpdates?

The thing is i need only an approximate position without blocking delay

Im trying this code from an `Activity` `onCreate` but the `providers.size()` is always zero

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);  
List<String> providers = lm.getProviders(true);

    Location l = null;

    for (int i=providers.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
       l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(providers.get(i));
       if (l != null) 
        break;
    }

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permisssion.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permisssion.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](http://www.androidsnippets.com/get-the-phones-last-known-location-using-locationmanager) code snippet.

Comment: im actually tested that but keep getting providers.size()=0. i do have the uses-permission in my manifest and gps is on but still provider are not returned

Comment: It's working alright. Lets say user buy his device in New York and then turn it on in japan, and install my app. is there a chance my app would get the NY coordinate now since i get old values right?

Comment: it´s currently 404 , please try to provide the code better then a link

Answer (score 2):

Even though you can get the last known location from location manager its may be outdated so its better to get all providers list and check the most current location so that it can be more accurate

```
LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        List<String> providers = manager.getAllProviders();
        Location loc;

        for (int i = 0; i < providers.size(); i++) {

            loc = manager.getLastKnownLocation(providers.get(i));
            loc.getTime();
            /*
             * put your code here
             * compare loc from providers to get the most 
             * recent location
             */
        }
}
```